# How to merge pdfs in order of their name in Linux Terminal?

Tags: debian, pdf, pop-os

I have 86 PDFs that I don't want to share on the internet and merge with online tools.
I am using the PopOS Linux distro and I would like to merge it using the terminal.

PDF names are like `1.SubjectA`, `2. SubjectB`
(start with Number. , so they are well ordered)
Here is what I found but none of them are merging in order:

```bash
qpdf --empty --pages *.pdf -- out.pdf
```

Example file names:

```
1. Why to learn System and Network.pdf
2. Network, Hardwares, LAN-WAN.pdf
3. Protocols-Ports, OSI-TCP IP.pdf
4. ARP, ICMP, RFC, IANA.pdf
...
```

Pattern is
Number + .(dot) + space + name

Comment: Create a bash script with this content (and give execution perms): `qpdf --empty --pages "$@" -- out.pdf` and in your terninal type: `printf -- "%s\0" ./*.pdf | sort -zV | xargs -0 ./script`

Answer (score 0):

I would try to tune a sort command to match the required order:

```
qdf --empty --pages `ls *.pdf |sort -n` -- out.pdf
```

This approach will not work if filenames include spaces.
In this case, I propose:

```
find . -name "*.pdf" -type f -print0  |sort -V -z |xargs -0 qpdf --empty --pages {} -- out.pdf
```

If this does not fill your needs, please explain the problems you find.

Comment: Thank you for your time and comment. Here is what I got:
`qpdf: error at * in numeric range *`
I edited the post with the examples of file names.

Comment: This method is similar to [Bash pitfall number 1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29), equally flawed.

Comment: `qpdf: unknown argument ./1. Why to learn System and Network.pdf`

Answer (score 0):

With all the files in the one directory
one can get rid of the spaces and commas in the filenames,
then sort them and merge them, thus:

```
 find . -name "*" -type f | rename 's/ /_/g'
 find . -name "*" -type f | rename 's/,/_/g'
 ls | sort -n | pdfunite *.pdf merged.pdf
```